# Trying to use latest Mesa breaks OpenGL on amdgpu in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, opengl, mesa

I'm having an issue upgrading to the latest Mesa drivers (anything >= 19.3) from any external repository, in this case oibaf.

In the past I did not have any issues doing this, but a couple of months ago, when using an external graphics driver repo (like oibaf or padoka), OpenGL would be broken after upgrading the drivers.
It does work with the default Mesa 19.2 that comes with Ubuntu 19.10, but as soon as I try to use anything newer in terms of graphics drivers, it breaks OpenGL and I have no idea why.

Here is some info about my system:

```
# uname -a

Linux valhalla 5.5.9 #1 SMP Sun Mar 15 18:38:51 CET 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
# inxi -Gx

Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 vendor: Sapphire Limited driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
           bus ID: 0c:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.7 driver: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: N/A v: N/A direct render: N/A
```

```
# LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo

name of display: :0.0
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  53
  Current serial number in output stream:  52
```

```
Mesa version: Mesa 20.1.0-devel (git-b93a195 2020-03-14 eoan-oibaf-ppa)
```

```
Graphic Card: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT
```

I have two config files for Xorg:

```
# /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "AMDgpu"
    MatchDriver "amdgpu"
    Driver "amdgpu"
EndSection
```

```
# /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-graphics.conf 

Section "Module"
    Load "glx"
    Load "amdgpu"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon R5700XT"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

`vulkaninfo` does print it's usual stuff, so this seems to be still working.

I have this issue for quite a while now and always reverted back to the default graphics stack, but I really would like to figure out why it's broken all of a sudden. Yet I'm pretty much out of ideas where I can even start to find the issue, less how to fix it, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like I've fixed it. I had a couple of amdgpu packages installed. I've purged all amdgpu packages but these:
```
libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
```
Then I've added the oibaf repo, did an update & upgrade. Reboot and it worked.